Graph families with bounded diameter and logarithmic edge-connectivity
Let $G$ be a simple graph and let $|G|$ be its order, $D(G)$ its diameter and $\lambda(G)$ its edge-connectivity. I am looking for graph sequences $(G_n)_n$ of increasing order, i.e. $|G_{n+1}|>|G_n|$ $\forall n$ (and, in particular, $\lim_{n\to\infty}|G_n|=\infty$), such that:
(i) The diameter is upper bounded by a constant for every graph in the sequence, i.e. the sequence given by $D(G_n)$ is $O(1)$.
(ii) The edge-connectivity grows logarithmically (or poly-logarithmically, but not faster) with the order, i.e. the sequence given by $\lambda(G_n)$ is $\Theta(\log^k|G_n|)$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$ ($k\geq1$).
Are there any well-studied graph families out there with these two properties? I am thinking about something in the flavour of the hypercube graph family (but this does not serve my purposes because it does not meet condition (i)).

Show your efforts and so we can understand where are your doubts.

Are you interested in any examples satisfying i) and ii) (even if very artificial)?

With incresing you mean with respect to inclusion? Or with respect to the order?

@MathieuRundström: The less artificial the better :-)

@BrunoAndrades: I am editing my question to be more precise.

For each $n$ consider the graph $G_n$, each with $2n$ vertices, comprised of two disjoint copies of $K_n$ and exactly one edge $uv$ joining them. This family of graphs has diamater $3$ and edge connectivity $1$, while it's easy to see how $G_{n+1}\supset G_n$

EDIT: Since the question has been edited I'll edit in the comment I made originally. For every $k\geq 1$ there's a sequence of graphs that has $|G_n|$ srictly increasing, $\lambda(G_n)=\Theta(\log^k(|G_n|))$, $D(G_n)=3=O(1)$ and even more $G_n\subset G_{n+1}$, which is a property the question doesn't ask for but you get it for free and it's also a property the hypercubes have (For $k=0$ you can just use my orginal construction). Consider the family $G_n$ where each $G_n$ has $m=2^{2^n}$ vertices. And let $r=2^{kn}$ consider a clique $K=K_r$ and for each vertex we add $\frac mr-1$ vertices to form a $K_{m/r}$ such that these cliques are pairwise vertex disjoint. This family has $r\cdot\frac mr=m$ vertices, the diameter is $3$ since if two pairs are on the same clique, they're at distance $1$ and if they're in different cliques they can always get in at most $3$ steps to eachother by passing through $K$. And the connectivity is at most $r-1$ since if I delete the $r-1$ edges inside $K$ of one of its vertices, then I disconnect one of the $K_{m/r}$. It's also easy to convince oneself that no $r-2$ edges will suffice. Since $r-1=\log^km-1$ we proved what we wanted. It's also clear how to find a $G_n$ in $G_{n+1}$; simply consider $2^{2^n-kn}$ of the outer cliques and the graph induced by them will be a $G_n$
Notice that there was no need to take $m$ to be that large. I made it that large so that everything was trivially integers. But for every $m\geq 2$ you can just add floors and ceilings such that it works out, losing at most $O(\log m)$ vertices.
Regarding your second question in the comments, I'm not aware of such families having been studied before, but that doesn't mean much per se. I also don't know if this construction has been considered before, I came up with it while thinking about the question

Does a constant sequence grow logarithmically?

@MishaLavrov Under my interpretation it does, I interpreted it as $\tilde{O}(1)$, if you want $\tilde{\Theta}(1)$ then you can consider $\log n$ $K_r$'s with $r=n/\log n$ and exactly one edge between each of those pairs. It has edge connectivity $\log n-1$ and diameter $3$

@BrunoAndrades Thank you for your answer. The first one does not serve my purposes because I want the edge-connectivity to grow, as I hope it is clear now after editing my question. However, your modified construction does. Do you happen to know other families with these properties that have been considered before in the literature?

@JULIOIÑIGODEVICENTEMAJUA I added an edit to my answer to cover your question. Hope it can be accepted now
